# ¿Cómo creo un metodo que escriba o cree un archivo html en ruby?

Tags: ruby

Tengo que crear un método que reciba dos *strings*, este método creará un archivo *index.html* y pondrá como párrafo cada uno de los *strings* recibidos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el recorrido para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas, la idea principal es que pongas lo que has intentado o los errores con los que te has encontrado. Para mas información te recomiendo visitar estos enlaces: [ask] y [mcve]

Comment: Gracias por la info, lo hare de inmediato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear un archivo puedes utilizar `File.open` con la opción `"w"`, y para escribir en el archivo utiliza el método `write`; por ejemplo:

```
def create_index(*strings)
  File.open("index.html", "w") do |f|
    f.write("<html>\n")
    f.write("<head>\n<title>Mi título</title>\n</head>\n")
    f.write("<body>\n")

    strings.each { |string| f.write("<p>#{string}</p>\n") }

    f.write("</body>\n</html>\n")
  end
end
```

Al especificar `*strings` como parámetro, te permite llamar el método con uno o más *strings*, no limitas el método a únicamente uno.

Por ejemplo, puedes llamar la función anterior así:

```
s1 = "Párrafo uno"
s2 = "Párrafo dos"

create_index(s1, s2)
```

Lo cual crearía el archivo *index.html* con el siguiente contenido:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Mi título</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Párrafo uno</p>
<p>Párrafo dos</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

También podrías utilizar *heredoc* y llamar `File.write`, haciendo tu código ligeramente más eficiente y legible:

```
def create_index(*strings)
  contents = <<~HTML
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Mi título</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        #{strings.map { |s| "<p>" + s + "</p>" }.join }
      </body>
    </html>
  HTML

  File.write("index.html", contents)
end
```

Resultado:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mi título</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Párrafo uno</p><p>Párrafo dos</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sabrías como contar la cantidad de strings que se pasan por argumento?

Comment: @UpsetGrade `*` genera un arreglo, en este caso `strings`, por lo tanto sólo necesitas utililizar el método `size`: `strings.size`.

Comment: genero el arreglo vacío o le paso *strings?

Comment: @UpsetGrade Al definir los argumentos como `*strings`, lo que estás haciendo es crear un arreglo llamado `strings` con todos los argumentos que especifiques al momento de llamar el método. Entonces el arreglo ya existe, solo debes llamar `.size` directamente en el. `strings` es el nombre de la variable que almacena el arreglo, puedes llamarlo de cualquier forma.

Comment: Gracias Gerry !